# Put a div bellow a full back-ground video

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm having some problems with an full background-video. Because I cannot put any other content below the video. Like another section etc.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="title">Quer achar o emprego dos seus sonhos?</h1>
      <p class="sub-title">Com a Joobber é fácil!</p>
          <video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
              <source src="video/work.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 new-section">
      <h1>NEW SECTION</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<%- include partials/footer.ejs %>
```

And here is my css:

```
#background{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


.title{
  text-align: center;
}
.sub-title{
  text-align: center;
}

.new-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: black;
}
```

The problem is that any content that I create, be in the middle of the video container. I wanna put it below.

A print screen about what is happening:[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82qMa.jpg)

Comment: I think its because of ```position:fixed;``` to your ```#background```..

Comment: I think so. Dou you know how can I make full background video with position absolute? When I change to absolute some things getta kinda weird

Answer (score 0):

try "padding-top: 200px:" on your Title and see what happens. (The number will have to be adjusted.) There are some other options, but I think that should work.

(Other options, I think you could "float:center;" your video and then "clear:both;" your Title or you could put your Title in a new div below your video...etc. )

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider wrapping your video element and making the wrapper relative positioned:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
        <source src="video/work.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

.video-wrapper {
    postition: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
#background {
   position: absolute;
}
```

The rest of your content should flow properly. You won't need to wrap the code above in Bootstrap code.